# JQuery UI datepicker magically stopped pulling correct month

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

EDIT:  I just made a jsfiddle to demonstrate the problem here: http://jsfiddle.net/GvjRd/3/

I have a web tool that uses the JQuery UI datepicker.  It has been working smoothly for weeks, but then all of a sudden it stopped working today.  No matter what day/month/year I pick on the calendar, when I select a day and call `alert(currentTime.getMonth());` it returns '7'.  It returns the day/year just fine.

I proceeded to test just the datepicker on its own, making a very simple page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <link type="text/css" href="ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="demos.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $("#datepicker").datepicker({
                onSelect : function(dateText, inst) {
                    var currentTime = new Date();
                    currentTime.setDate($("#datepicker").datepicker("getDate").getDate());
                    alert(currentTime.getMonth());
                }
            });
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
            Date:
            <input type="text" id="datepicker">
</body>
```

Even on this page, no matter what day/month/year combination I choose, the alert says '7'.  Anyone else having this problem?

Comment: Did my answer not work? jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GvjRd/8/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Months in JavaScript are zero based so 7 = the 8th month, or August.

In your example, you're setting the `currentTime` to today and then only changing the day of that date object to the date picked on the calendar, leaving the month and year unchanged. Therefore, `currentTime.getMonth()` will always show the month that the running the script in, not the date picked from the calendar. To do that, use `currentTime.setMonth($("#datepicker").datepicker("getDate").getMonth());`

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/GvjRd/7/)**

Comment: I am aware of this.  For some reason, no matter what date the user selects the datepicker says that the date chosen is in August.

Comment: You're not using the date the user picks, that would be `dateText`. You're using `var currentTime = new Date();`. At least in the fiddle you posted.

Comment: You're right - I had to replace 'currentTime.setDate($("#datepicker").datepicker("getDate").getDate());'
with 
'currentTime = $(this).datepicker( 'getDate' );'

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you don't set the `currentTime` variable ahead of time:

```
$(function() {
                $("#datepicker").datepicker({
                    onSelect : function(dateText, inst) {
                        var currentTime;
                        currentTime = $("#datepicker").datepicker("getDate");
                        alert(currentTime.getMonth() + 1);
                    }
                });
            });​
```